# MySQL Search Within Database (Table Search)

Tags: mysql, search

Alright, I'm trying to write a query to display all the tables that contain a certain prefix. Something like what is displayed below (but is obviously incorrect)

```
SELECT TABLES LIKE chat_
```

So any table that has the chat prefix, would be displayed. I plan on formatting the output, so it's not going to be a raw output, and I also understand that "what idiot would display table names publicly", and security measures are being taken to prevent that "accidental" table drop (just trying to avoid a flame war). So, how is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'chat_%';
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought this is how you would do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use regular expressions, which allows a little more flexibility (though a performance cost):

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE tables_in_db REGEXP 'chat.*';
```

*In this example, replace **db** with the database name of concern.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "in some_db first" before where like below

```
 SHOW TABLES in test_server_service where 'table' regexp 't_*';
```